# weighted zscore within groups

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Consider the following dataframe `df`

```
np.random.seed([3,1415])
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
        S=np.random.rand(20),
        W=np.random.rand(20),
        G=np.random.choice(list('ABCD'), 20)
    ))

print(df)

    G         S         W
0   B  0.444939  0.278735
1   D  0.407554  0.609862
2   C  0.460148  0.085823
3   B  0.465239  0.836997
4   A  0.462691  0.739635
5   A  0.016545  0.866059
6   D  0.850445  0.691271
7   C  0.817744  0.377185
8   B  0.777962  0.225146
9   C  0.757983  0.435280
10  C  0.934829  0.700900
11  A  0.831104  0.700946
12  C  0.879891  0.796487
13  A  0.926879  0.018688
14  D  0.721535  0.700566
15  D  0.117642  0.900749
16  D  0.145906  0.764869
17  C  0.199844  0.253200
18  B  0.437564  0.548054
19  A  0.100702  0.778883
```

I want to perform a weighted zscore of the `'S'` column using weights `'W'` within each group defined by `'G'`

So that we know what the definition of weighted zscore is, this is how you'd calculate it over the entire set:

```
(df.S - (df.S * df.W).mean()) / df.S.std()
```

***Question(s)***
*What is the most elegant way to calculate this?*
*What is the most key-stroke efficient way to calculate this?*
*What is the most time-efficient way to calculate this?*

I calculated the answer as

```
0     1.291729
1     0.288806
2     0.394302
3     1.414926
4     0.619677
5    -0.461462
6     1.625974
7     1.645083
8     3.312825
9     1.436054
10    2.054617
11    1.512449
12    1.862456
13    1.744537
14    1.236770
15   -0.586493
16   -0.501159
17   -0.516180
18    1.246969
19   -0.257527
dtype: float64
```

Comment: You're not looking for something like this, are you? `df.groupby('G').apply(lambda x: (x.S - (x.S * x.W).mean()) / x.S.std())` ... I'm thinking you would split by group and apply each group's weights to the z-score calculation.

Comment: @not_a_robot ohhh yes I am.  My opinion of it will be given if you post it as an answer and receive your up-vote.

Comment: That's an unusual definition of weighted zscore.  Ordinarily you need a term to normalize to the total weight per group, but you don't seem to have one.

Comment: @DSM its less about the accuracy of the terms I chose to use and more about that specific formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
>>> df.groupby('G').apply(lambda x: (x.S - (x.S * x.W).mean()) / x.S.std())
G    
A  4     0.619677
   5    -0.461462
   11    1.512449
   13    1.744537
   19   -0.257527
B  0     1.291729
   3     1.414926
   8     3.312825
   18    1.246969
C  2     0.394302
   7     1.645083
   9     1.436054
   10    2.054617
   12    1.862456
   17   -0.516180
D  1     0.288806
   6     1.625974
   14    1.236770
   15   -0.586493
   16   -0.501159
Name: S, dtype: float64
```

We first split on each group in `G`, then apply the weighted z-score function to each group dataframe.

Comment: I'd call this the utilitarian approach :-)

Comment: Sure thing. I wasn't able to reproduce your calculated output above, so it was my best guess, really. Cheers.

Comment: I got no other bites...You're the winner :-)

Answer (score 0):

## `transform`

```
P = df.S * df.W
m = P.groupby(df.G).transform('mean')
z = df.groupby('G').S.transform('std')
(df.S - m) / z

0     1.291729
1     0.288806
2     0.394302
3     1.414926
4     0.619677
5    -0.461462
6     1.625974
7     1.645083
8     3.312825
9     1.436054
10    2.054617
11    1.512449
12    1.862456
13    1.744537
14    1.236770
15   -0.586493
16   -0.501159
17   -0.516180
18    1.246969
19   -0.257527
dtype: float64
```

## `agg` + `join` + `eval`

```
f = dict(S=dict(Std='std'), P=dict(Mean='mean'))
stats = df.assign(P=df.S * df.W).groupby('G').agg(f)
stats.columns = stats.columns.droplevel()
df.join(stats, on='G').eval('(S - Mean) / Std')

0     1.291729
1     0.288806
2     0.394302
3     1.414926
4     0.619677
5    -0.461462
6     1.625974
7     1.645083
8     3.312825
9     1.436054
10    2.054617
11    1.512449
12    1.862456
13    1.744537
14    1.236770
15   -0.586493
16   -0.501159
17   -0.516180
18    1.246969
19   -0.257527
dtype: float64
```

---

***naive timing***

[image]